# Solana dev communities

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

i am looking to join any discord communities of solana developers trying to get some help . if you any suggestions that will be much appreciated .(i already joined solana tech , so any other ones )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[LamportDAO](https://twitter.com/LamportDAO) and [The 76 Devs](https://twitter.com/the76devs) are both good Discords to be in.

Answer (score 0):

To add a few more niche discords depending on your tech stack:

Solana Mobile: https://discord.gg/solanamobile

Solana Collective: https://discord.gg/solanacollective

Metaplex: https://discord.gg/metaplex

Solana Flutter: https://discord.gg/M2kakEAX

Helius: https://discord.gg/helius

Solana Hackathon: https://discord.gg/eHTzGK2B